# Place bootstrap modal's close icon over the image

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal in page load i want to place a close icon over the image.Currently i am using a button to close the modal.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="hfc">
      <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="assets/frontend/img/use/1.jpg"/>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
         $(window).load(function(){        
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: did you just try to replace the button with a glyphicon?

Comment: yes but also that is come after the image not over the image

Comment: So it's a Css position problem. Have you tried setting `position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this way you can set on image

```
.hfc{
  position:relative;
}
.hfc img{
  width:100%;
}
.close{
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery('#mymodal').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.hfc{
  position:relative;
}
.hfc img{
  width:100%;
}
.close{
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="hfc">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
      </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```